# How to display JSON response to the view, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have just started learning AngularJS yesterday and building a app for practise to display images that the user enter in the search bar.

My code so far

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div id="content" ng-app="FlickerApp" ng-controller="MainController">

        <h3>Search images in real time!</h3>

          <input type="text" ng-model="searchPic" />
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showPics()">Search</button>

        <div id="flickerPics" >
          <ul ng-repeat="ph in data.photo">
            <li>
              {{ ph.id }}
              {{ response }}
              <img src="https://farm{{ ph.farm }}.staticflickr.com/{{ ph.server}}/{{ ph.id}}_{{ph.secret}}.jpg" 
              style="width:304px;height:228px;">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
```

and **JavaScript**

```
    angular.module("FlickerApp",[]).controller("MainController",                         
    function($scope, $http){

    $scope.showPics = function () {

    $http.get("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?   method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[API_KEY_HERE]&tags="  +$scope.searchPic+  "&in_gallery=1&is_getty=1&per_page=5&format=json&nojsoncallback=1")
.success(function(data){
  $scope.data = data.photos;
}).error(function(data, status){
    $scope.response = data + status;
    });
    }

    });
```

I have not entered the API key, the url works because i have tested it manually.

I am testing this on JSFiddle

Comment: can you put a sample response from this API ?

Comment: I receive nothing back from the API

Comment: what is this line doing then `$scope.data = data.photos;` ?

Comment: adding the photos object sent back as JSON, this thing works because i have used it in other app, the only difference here is that i am adding a button and have the get method in event, its like the event is not responding

Comment: @Manu why is there are space in your url?
and did u check response in your network tab in developers tool?

Comment: that was me trying to format the URL, and i got this 

`Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

Comment: Upgrade your version of AngularJS. They removed the `X-Requested-With` header default inclusion in [`v1.1.1`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade your AngularJS version. Seems you're using one of the older ones that sets the `X-Requested-With` request header which isn't compatible with most CORS configurations.

There is however a work-around. Try this

```
$http.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/', {
  params: {
    method: 'flickr.photos.search',
    api_key: [API_KEY_HERE],
    tags: $scope.searchPic,
    in_gallery: 1,
    is_getty: 1,
    per_page: 5,
    format: 'json',
    nojsoncallback: 1
  },
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': null
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data.photos;
})
```

Even if you upgrade, I highly recommend keeping the `params` config as above. You wouldn't need the `header` config though.

Comment: i solved it by adding `jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK` to the URL, i still don't understand what it is though, i made a IOS app and used nojsoncallback and that worked but not with angularjs

Comment: @Manu that would be for making a JSONP request. If you're doing that, you should use [`$http.jsonp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) and set `{jsonpCallbackParam: 'jsoncallback'}` (unless you're not upgrading that is)

Comment: Yes i used jsonp, however just tried your code it works! i don't understand the response.data.photos why not just response.photos?

Comment: @Manu you should definitely upgrade Angular though. Whatever you're using is obviously **very** old

Comment: i used plunker to add the angularjs file `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @Manu [`v1.0.7` - Released May 22, 2013](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/releases/tag/v1.0.7)

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
 $http.get("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[API_KEY_HERE]&tags="  +$scope.searchPic+  "&in_gallery=1&is_getty=1&per_page=5&format=json&nojsoncallback=1") 
 .then(function(result){
    $scope.data = result.data;
  }).error(function(data, status){
    $scope.response = data + status;
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not setting X-Requested-With header while requesting. This issue is due to CORS. Try to study CORS, it is very important thing while doing cross-domain requests.

Try to add headers in your request like following:

```
$http({
'url':'yourUrl',
'method':'get',
'headers': { 'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest'}
});
```

Comment: You've got it backwards. OP's code **is** sending the `X-Requested-With` header but the Flickr API is rejecting the request because of it

Comment: yep, my bad. I did not read your comment correctly. :) Anyways, good to know you got this